# Implement structure like wikipedia on node

Tags: 7, nodes

I want Implement structure in drupal like wikipedia, register user can change the node content but if admin(a role for this job) approve them the updated  node show to user,else the old version ( not changed ) show. drupal has revision feature but this it applied and not wait for admin approve the changes,any way exist in drupal to achieve this job?
In before project I did something like this but It was about user profile not on content, I used profile module ,but here I want work on content and nodes .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup a content moderation system for nodes using the [Workbench Moderation](https://drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) module